# buld error because of org.xml.sax.SAXParseException

Tags: java, android, xml, ant

I have this problem:

This is my AndroidManifest.xml (It was the only file that I edited before i see error):

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest android:versionCode="2"
          android:versionName="1.1"
          package="it.ptia.appsender"
          xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_MEDIA_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
  <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="3"
            android:targetSdkVersion="14" />
  <supports-screens android:largeScreens="true"
                    android:normalScreens="true"
                    android:smallScreens="false" />
  <application android:icon="@drawable/share_blue"
               android:label="Condividi app">

      <meta-data android:name="android.app.default_searchable" android:value=".SearchableActivity" /> 
    <activity android:label="Condividi app"
              android:name=".Launchalot">
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
      </intent-filter>
    </activity>
      <activity android:label="Condividi app" android:name=".SearchableActivity" > 
                <intent-filter >
                       <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                    </intent-filter> 
                <meta-data
                       android:name="android.app.searchable"
                       android:resource="@xml/searchable" /> 
             </activity> 
    </application>
    </manifest>
```

And this is ant debug (linux) error. I am using linux ubuntu and i've never seen it before now. :

```
    [gettype] [Fatal Error] :26:5: Element type "activity" must be followed by either attribute specifications, ">" or "/>".

BUILD FAILED
/home/edoardo/Script/android-sdk-linux/tools/ant/build.xml:388: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 26; columnNumber: 5; Element type "activity" must be followed by either attribute specifications, ">" or "/>".
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.DOMParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.DocumentBuilderImpl.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xpath.internal.jaxp.XPathImpl.evaluate(XPathImpl.java:463)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xpath.internal.jaxp.XPathImpl.evaluate(XPathImpl.java:510)
    at com.android.ant.GetTypeTask.execute(GetTypeTask.java:85)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:291)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor4.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:390)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:411)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1399)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTarget(Project.java:1368)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.DefaultExecutor.executeTargets(DefaultExecutor.java:41)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTargets(Project.java:1251)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.runBuild(Main.java:809)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.startAnt(Main.java:217)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher.run(Launcher.java:280)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:109)
--------------- linked to ------------------
javax.xml.xpath.XPathExpressionException
    at com.sun.org.apache.xpath.internal.jaxp.XPathImpl.evaluate(XPathImpl.java:468)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xpath.internal.jaxp.XPathImpl.evaluate(XPathImpl.java:510)
    at com.android.ant.GetTypeTask.execute(GetTypeTask.java:85)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:291)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor4.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:390)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:411)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1399)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTarget(Project.java:1368)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.DefaultExecutor.executeTargets(DefaultExecutor.java:41)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTargets(Project.java:1251)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.runBuild(Main.java:809)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.startAnt(Main.java:217)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher.run(Launcher.java:280)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:109)
Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 26; columnNumber: 5; Element type "activity" must be followed by either attribute specifications, ">" or "/>".
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.DOMParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.DocumentBuilderImpl.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xpath.internal.jaxp.XPathImpl.evaluate(XPathImpl.java:463)
    ... 18 more
```

What is the problem?

Comment: It looks like the parser is not seeing the file you posted:  it speaks of an "activity" element in line 26, but the last "activity" element in the document you posted starts in line 24, not line 26.  The error message suggests that the input the parser is seeing is not well formed (and specifically that the "activity" element at line 26 is lacking a right angle bracket to close its start-tag.

Comment: @C.M.Sperberg-McQueen But AndroidManifest.xml is the only xml file in my project that contains the word "activity"